# Strategy for Silverlight and Entity Framework solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, entity-framework

I am new to Silverlight and am developing an ASP.NET web application that requires a Silverlight project to record webcam audio/video streams.

The solution consists of a library project containing business entities such as [User], [BillingInfo], etc., and an ASP .NET Web Application.

Since Silverlight does not support EF, how can I use the strongly-typed entity objects from within Silverlight? I do not need access to the Context object but will require access to Entity classes.

I use Code First so have to mark Entities with Annotations which Silverlight will not recognize since the DataAnnotations assembly is not referencable. Switching to model-first is also an option (albeit less preferable) if required.

Has anyone dealt with a similar scenario? What is the best way to get strongly-typed entities in Silverlight. Any articles or references would help as well. Thank you.

Technologies (upgrade is an option if required):
ASP .NET Web Application (.NET 4)
Entity Framework 5
Silverlight 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight works very well with entity framework!

You could directly consume your entity through webservices as describe in this blog: http://geekswithblogs.net/berthin/archive/2011/05/29/ado_net_entityframework_from_silverlight.aspx

Or as Dave suggest, you could combine RIA services and Entity Framework, so you could use annotation http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2010/03/15/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-exposing-data-from-entity-framework.aspx

The combination of Silverlight and Entity Framework create a really powerfull ready to use business logic.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 5):

I would recomend giving [WCF RIA Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) a try. This will simplify the data access for your application and provide you with strongly typed entities on the Silverlight client side.